# Linked server in Sql Server 2014 invalid path

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am trying to create a linked server to foxpro tables using vfpoledb, but it gives me the error of "Invalid path or file name" when trying to put as source `\\xxx.xxx.x.x\same_names\abc` (xxx.xxx.x.x represents the server's IP address).

However, I have no problem trying with the parent folder: `\\xxx.xxx.x.x\same_names`.

The only thing that occurs to me is that there may be some limitation as to the length of the path, is there really any limitation or is it that I am doing something wrong?

Here is the script of the create linked server

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'BORRAR', @srvproduct=N'A', @provider=N'VFPOLEDB', @datasrc=N'\\xxx.xxx.0.8\DOCS\ION_ANDER\JAB\'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'BORRAR',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'BORRAR', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: Could you press the script button on the guid when creating the linked server and add the details here (anonimized where needed)? . The data source should be able to hold up to 4000 unicode characters

Comment: Ok, i edited to put the script

Comment: Have you seen this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f8f966e5-08f1-4934-902b-7ea65a31e3c1/oledb-provider-vfpoledb-for-linked-server-returned-message-quotinvalid-path-or-file-namequot?forum=sqldataaccess)? Seems like somebody had the same error and had to configure Kerberos authentication (SPN & delegation) / service account issues.

Comment: That´s it!!, i need to create the linked server with impersonation using a domain user and now works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it works now